# How to use pgp to send email?

Tags: email, security, pgp, internet-security, openpgp

So I was reading a post where it seems the author provides its email through a pgp. How am I supposed to use that pgp to send him an email?

https://decovar.dev/about/#contacts

Answer (score 1):

[Pretty Good Privacy (PGP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)
is an encryption program that can encrypt your mail so only the
recipient can read it, for the security of your email if it is
intercepted by some third party.

However, for mundane email there is no need to encrypt the email.
In other words, PGP is not mandatory.
Only use the provided public PGP key in order to tell secrets.
The recipient can still receive and understand an unencrypted email.

For sending encrypted email using PGP, please consult the
documentation of the email client that you are using.

Comment: So the actual email address (the destination) is embedded on that pgp? Can I decrypt it? If not, how the email client knows to where it should be sent? Who decrypts the actual email address and redirects it to the right destination?

Comment: No, the email address isn't encoded, only the contents are encrypted. An email can have encrypted contents, or can have unencypted plain-text contents. It's up to you, the sender, to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the key has its owner's email address embedded in it.

First download the public key and import it into the "keyring" of whatever PGP software you're using (e.g. GnuPG command line, Kleopatra, OpenKeychain, etc). It will show up in the program's "key list" with the key owner's name and email address.

If you only want to send a regular, unencrypted message – just copy the email address from the list and send it a message as normal, through Gmail or whatever (PGP doesn't need to get involved further).

If you specifically want to send an *PGP-encrypted* message, that's still done mostly through your mail app, but it highly depends on *which* mail app you're using. Some of them (e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird) have PGP integration, so you just check the "Encrypt (PGP/MIME)" menu item and it selects the keys for each recipient. Others (e.g. Gmail) would require copying the message into PGP for encryption, then copying back the encrypted version into the mail app. It's a topic for a separate question.

If you don't want to bother installing any PGP software at all, then download the key and run it through a Base64 decoder. Among all the binary data you'll see the owner's `Name <email>` in plain text.

Comment: On macOS base64 -D < [retif-public.asc](https://decovar.dev/about/retif-public.asc) > outputfile.txt? That's not showing any e-mail address here